# Rally CA Agile Central Custom App showing with blank table lines

Tags: javascript, rally

I have got a code snippet (custom Rally App) to list all re-opened defects. I think it's working fine except one small glitch. The table has got blank rows. Like this - [image] 
The code I have is -

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http:/...
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2002-2011  Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved. -->

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="Name" content="App: Defects by Closer"/>
    <meta name="Version" content="2012.01.14"/>
    <meta name="Vendor" content="Rally Software"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.33/sdk.js?apiVersion=1.29"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    /*
         Copyright (c) 2002-2011  Rally Software Development Corp. All rights reserved.
         DefectsByCloser.js
         */
        function DefectsByCloser(rallyDataSource) {
            var releaseDiv, tableDiv;
            var releaseDropdown;
            var table;
            var wait = null;

            // private method the builds the table of defects and associated info
            function showResults(results) {
                if (wait) {
                    wait.hide();
                    wait = null;
                }
                if (results.defects.length === 0) {
                    tableDiv.innerHTML = "No relevant defects associated with the selected release were found";
                    return;
                }

                var config =
                { 'columnKeys'   : ['FormattedID' , 'Name',  'State',  'Revision Number',    'ClosedBy',     'Description' ] ,
                    'columnHeaders': ['Formatted ID', 'Name',  'Status', 'Revision<br>Number', 'Closed By',     'Description' ] ,
                    'columnWidths' : ['80px',         '360px', '60px',       '60px',               '120px' ,               '500px'    ]
                };
                table = new rally.sdk.ui.Table(config);

                var linkConfig = null;
                var defectLink = null;

                var cd = null; // for defect.ClosedDate formatting
                var i, j, defect;

                for (i = 0; i < results.defects.length; i++) {
                    defect = results.defects[i];
                    //create link to defect
                    linkConfig = {item: {FormattedID: defect.FormattedID, "_ref" : defect._ref}};
                    defectLink = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Link(linkConfig);     

                        for (j = 0; j < defect.RevisionHistory.Revisions.length; j++) {
                            var revision = defect.RevisionHistory.Revisions[j];
                            var defectName = defect.Name + '';
                            if (revision.Description.search("Unresolved") !== -1 && defectName.trim() != '') { 
                                console.log('defectName:' + defectName);
                                table.setCell(i, 0, defectLink.renderToHtml());
                                table.setCell(i, 1, defect.Name);
                                table.setCell(i, 2, defect.State);                                                                                                                        
                                table.setCell(i, 3, '' + revision.RevisionNumber);
                                table.setCell(i, 4, '' + revision.User._refObjectName);
                                table.setCell(i, 5, '' + revision.Description);
                                break;  //only show the most recent result if defect was reopened/reclosed
                            }
                        }
                }
                //console.log(tableDiv);
                table.display(tableDiv);
           }

            //private method to query for defects when release selection changes
            function runMainQuery() {
                if (table) {
                    table.destroy();            
                    table = null;
                }

                tableDiv.innerHTML = "";
                var queryConfig =
                {
                    key   : "defects",
                    type  : "Defect",
                    fetch : "ObjectID,FormattedID,Name,ClosedDate,RevisionHistory,Revisions,RevisionNumber,Description,User",
                    order : "FormattedID",
                };

                wait = new rally.sdk.ui.basic.Wait({});
                wait.display('wait');

                rallyDataSource.findAll(queryConfig, showResults);
            }

            //private method to start building controls on page
            //page consists of a dropdown to select the release and the table to hold the query results
            function initPage() {
                tableDiv = document.getElementById('table');
                runMainQuery();
            }

            // only public method
            this.display = function() {        
                rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.setHelpTopic("232");
                rally.sdk.ui.AppHeader.showPageTools(true);

                initPage();
            };        
        }    

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        rally.addOnLoad(function() {
            var rallyDataSource = new rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource('__WORKSPACE_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_OID__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__',
                    '__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__');
            var defectsByCloser = new DefectsByCloser(rallyDataSource);
            defectsByCloser.display();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="release" style="float:left"></div>
<div id="wait" style="float:left; height: 16px; width: 24px;"></div>
<div id="table" style="clear:both;padding-top:15px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Disclaimer**: I have limited knowledge with Javascript and Rally App SDK. Please help me to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This app is written using the deprecated App SDK 1.x, so I'll admit I'm not an expert here.  My hunch though is that your data is malformed- or at least it's not in the same format that the loop where you're building out your table content is expecting.

I'd try setting some debug statements, console logging things in that area to see why the data isn't in the expected shape.  The other possible problem is maybe you're not fetching all the fields you need in the RallyDataSource.findAll?